# Is there a Java Open source Library for parsing Excel 2007 Files?

Tags: java, excel, open-source, excel-2007

Is there a Java Open source Library for parsing Excel 2007 Files?

Answer (score 9):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html)  looks promising.

Answer (score 5):

Apache POI is the pure java answer to the question. 2007 format support is in beta right now.

OpenXLS may support it already (if GPL is fine for you). The commercial version of the same product (ExtenXLS) does support it.

Although not strictly part of the question, I should point out that any rewrite of access to Excel files will always have some deficiency over the original, so [Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html)'s advice is a good alternative, if you need it.

Answer (score 3):

Apache POI

Answer (score 2):

From http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html

DDF - Dreadful Drawing Format
This package contains classes for decoding the Microsoft Office Drawing format otherwise known as escher henceforth known in POI as the Dreadful Drawing Format.

HPSF - Horrible Property Set Format

HSSF - Horrible Spreadsheet Format

I love those guys. We will try to use POI to read Excel files, I will look at the JExcel solution too.

Comment: Just a comment, I used POI to read Excel files and it worked really well.

Answer (score 1):

http://openxml4j.org/

Comment: openxml4j has been added to the POI api.

Answer (score 1):

Not POI.  Andy Khan's [JExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) is what you want.

Comment: From the link, it does not say it supports Excel "2007"

Answer (score 1):

I did an assessment of poi and jexcel some time ago and jexcel was far superior.  They both use a lot of memory though in the case that you have very large datafiles.  By this I mean, I was not able to figure out how to construct an excel file through a stream, such that I didn't have to load the entire file in memory.

Comment: This is a big deal for files that are created or edited by big days-generating programs. I sometimes push Excel to its limits. Streaming may be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently comparing JExcelApi and Apache POI. POI supports Office 2007 in Beta and looks like the best option (in many ways)