# Read Microsoft Word Documents into Plain Text (DOC, DOCX) in Java

Tags: java, ms-word, docx, doc

I'm looking for something in Java to read in Word documents to process their text.. all I need is there text, nothing fancy.  I know about Apache POI, however it doesn't include support for DOCX right now, anything out there?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't require formatting information, images and all other fancy stuff, then the job is lot easier. Just some 5 to 10 lines of code will do.

1. Treat DOCX as a zip file. It consists a bunch of files which includes 'document.xml'. Use ZipInputStream and extract that file alone. (you may use your favorite zip utility and open docx and see for yourself!)
2. Use a SAX parser and read contents between node body/p/r/t - voila you got the text!

This is applicable only if you need the **text only**.

Comment: Hi Joseph can you plz write down the short code here ? It would be of GREAT HELP to me...

Answer (score 3):

With some googling I found [OpenXML4J](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openxml4j/). This might solve your issue. I have not used this before I am sure someone in the community will have better insight.

Note: This is a duplicate question. This has the solution plus a bit of discussion. [Link to the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836769/is-there-a-java-open-source-library-for-parsing-excel-2007-files)

Comment: Is it reasonable to keep both questions, given that one is asking about Word doc format and the other Excel?  They may be two subsets of one larger document format spec, I honestly don't know.

Comment: I believe it is a duplicate because each question is asking about office 2007 java api. The other question, IMHO, does answer the mail. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try [apache poi](http://poi.apache.org/) - it can handle doc, docx, xls, xlsx, ppt, pptx.

Another production-level solution is OpenOffice in headless mode which can even be used in a server-side scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You could try docx4j; see http://dev.plutext.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/TextUtils.java