# how to import .doc files from sd card into application database?

Tags: android

I want to import .doc files from sdcard into my application and also in database of my application but when i am importing file text is not displaying correctly. It is showing symbols characters. How to change format from .doc to .txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.doc is a Microsoft Word document file format which is not a plain text file. Its a binary file. So if you want to show only text, use a plain ASCII (.txt) file. If you want to show text with formatting or images then consider using HTML with WebView.

Comment: @Mudassir I would like to import .txt and .doc files and then show it in edit text

Comment: You can of course import .txt files as they are plain text files, but this is not the case with .doc files. To do so you may definitely need some converter sort of thing. I don't know if MSWord doc converter is available for Android. However one approach can be, place the .doc files on a server and fetch the contents of these .doc files on your Android device through a web service.

Comment: But if i have downloaded .apk file of convertor than also how can i include its classes in my application

Comment: As I know, we cannot use the classes of an .apk. If you downloaded a converter, then better search for some APIs for converter.

Comment: Then you should look for some other option. Can you tell me, exactly what do you want to implement?

Comment: ya sure..........i want to import .txt,.doc and .rtf files from sdcard into my application database and that document file is then shown in edit text. In edit text i can also update the text of the document in which is updated in database file only as on importing i have to make a copy of document file into the database. I am able to import .txt files but not .rtf and .doc files. And want to import that also.

Comment: Hmmm... Cannot you create the database from imported files on the computer and then use that ready database on Android?

Comment: No, database is already created by me from android application. I just want to copy imported file into that database

Comment: Are you sure, that there is no API available to read Word docs in Android? Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263951/read-microsoft-word-documents-into-plain-text-doc-docx-in-java

Comment: But this question also includes parsing and i am not using any parsing. And this ques. is not helping me

Comment: If you want to use Word or RTF docs on Android device, I think you have to implement a parser. And If you don't to use parser then, one more solution is to convert them to plain text files on computer then use those plain text files on Android device.

Comment: ya...........thanks but i want word file to convert into plaintext on android application installed on android device without using parsers

Comment: Buddy, I already told you, doc is a binary format hence can't be treated as plain (ASCII) text. You've to go either way. Let me know if you have any other option.

Comment: no.........................how could i implement parsing when there is no need and application not using it and how could i use it for changing format

Comment: How could you say that parsing is not needed while there is no other option available?

Comment: I mean to say in my application parsing is not used. Then  how could i do that.

Comment: As I know, there is no other way than we've discussed above.

Answer (score 1):

The .doc is a complex binary format and you will not be able to accomplish that easy. Feel free to read the specification here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313105(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: i doesn't want to know about formats. I want to change format of .doc file into .txt file without changing file contents through android programming