# Using OpenGrok to index Microsoft Office documents etc

Tags: svn, search, indexing, repository, opengrok

I was wondering if it is at all possible to use OpenGrok to index PPT, XLS, DOC etc formats. Would this have to be programmed by myself or is there already a plugin/method of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue on OpenGROK available here https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/issues/492
Though it is waiting since 2013 on a plugin interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no dedicated analyzer to extract data from these types of documents, however it should be possible to implement one based on the Java libraries listed in [Read Microsoft Word Documents into Plain Text (DOC, DOCX) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263951/read-microsoft-word-documents-into-plain-text-doc-docx-in-java) (e.g. Apache POI or Apache Tika)

Feel free to file a new issue on https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/issues